# PHP OOP newbie - Need to get $_POST data into a variable

Tags: php, oop

I was basically playing around with OOP and was creating a way to validate and sanitise input when I started to run into problems sanitising and then performing further validation. What I'm looking for is to take the posted `$_POST['name']` data, sanitise the input to remove any numbers and validate that the data left is neither `null` or numeric characters.

But I cant get the sanitised input saved to `$sanitised`, It seems to be empty, but when I replace

```
$sanitised=$fv->noNumbers($_POST['name']);
```

with

```
$sanitised=preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $_POST['name']);
```

everything works fine, so I think I'm messing up something in this `$sanitised` variable.

I wanna learn so either a solution to this or a "you're an idiot and doing it all wrong" would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
    class formSanitise {

        public function noNumbers($value) {
            $value = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $value);
        }
        public function isEmpty($value) {
                    return (!isset($value) || trim($value) == '') ? true : false;
        }
        public function isAlpha($value) {
            return preg_match('/[^a-z]/i', $value) ? false : true;
        }
?>
```

> processor.php

```
<?php
    include('class.formSanitise.php');
    $fv = new formSanitise();

    $sanitised= $fv->noNumbers($_POST['name']);

    if ($fv->isEmpty($sanitised)) {
        $fv->addError('Name', 'Please enter something');
    }
    if (!$fv->isAlpha($sanitised)) {
        $fv->addError('Name', 'Please enter your name');
    }
?>
```

Comment: `noNumbers` doesn't *return* any value.

Comment: Oh, do you know how i could go about fixing this so it did return a value?

Comment: Er, add a `return $value;` statement? See [SomeKittens's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027155/1233508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to create a [return](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) in `noNumbers` or pass `$value` [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Return method:

```
public function noNumbers($value) {
            return preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $value);
        }
```

Reference

```
public function noNumbers(&$value) {
            $value = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $value);
        }
```

`returning` a value means that `$value` is an entirely different variable, and will be assigned to `$sanitized` when it's returned from the function.  Passing by reference means that `$value` is the *exact same variable* as the one you passed to `noNumbers` and as such, anything that happens to the variable inside the function will happen to the variable that has been passed in.

Comment: Awesome thanks! could you very briefly explain the different use for return vs reference methods?

Comment: @Dark Sure!  I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code snippet the function noNumbers does not return any value.The argument passed to the function has a scope within that function only and in order  to make that value available to calling function there must be a return statement within function which will return the value to the calling function .Alternatively you can pass the  value to function by reference .